# Passing variables between release pipelines in azure (trigger azure pipeline extension)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-extensions

I have a requirement to pass data between 2 release pipelines (to trigger 2nd pipeline on completion of 1st pipeline).

Can we pass variables dynamically between azure RELEASE pipelines using trigger an Azure DevOps pipeline **extension**?

I tried this blog but unable to find/understand if we can use "output variables" to pass data between azure release pipelines.

https://msftplayground.com/2019/02/trigger-a-pipeline-from-an-azure-devops-pipeline/

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- ***Output variables*** are created by the pipeline and referenced by the other tasks in the pipeline, it means they are dynamic and refers to the result of a particular task.
- These cannot be defined statically.
- After running the task in the pipeline, output variables value can be known.
  There are two different ways to create output variables :
- By building support for the variable in the task itself
- Setting the value ad-hoc in a script

Below example is defining a task with the name  `SomeTask` that natively creates an output variable called out.

In a task within that same job, you can reference that variable using  `$(SomeTask.out)`.

```
steps:
- task: MyTask@1
name: SomeTask
- script: echo $(SomeTask.out)
```

For the detailed information regarding how to create output variables and pass between the pipelines, please refer [azure devops output variables.](https://www.nigelfrank.com/blog/azure-devops-output-variables/)